# Tikz array access problem

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can't access the array elements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}

\def\PatternArray{%
horizontal lines,%
vertical lines,%
north east lines,%
north west lines,%
grid,%
crosshatch,%
dots,%
crosshatch dots,%
fivepointed stars,%
sixpointed stars,%
bricks,%
checkerboard}

\begin{document}

essai

\pgfmathparse{\PatternArray[0]}
\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}

\newcommand\PatternArray{{%
  "horizontal lines",%
  "vertical lines",%
  "checkerboard"}}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{\PatternArray[0]}
\pgfmathresult

\pgfmathparse{\PatternArray[2]}
\pgfmathresult

\end{document}
```

There must be an additional pair of braces around the items; non numeric items should be surrounded by double quotes.

Maybe you'd like this different approach. Indexing starts from 1, but you can also count from the end with negative indices. The input is easier, because leading and trailing spaces are removed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definearray}{mm}
 {
  \clist_gclear_new:c { g_tarass_array_#1_clist }
  \clist_gset:cn  { g_tarass_array_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getarrayitem}{mm}
 {
  \clist_item:cn { g_tarass_array_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getarraylength}{m}
 {
  \clist_count:c  { g_tarass_array_#1_clist }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definearray{Pattern}{
  horizontal lines,
  vertical lines,
  north east lines,
  north west lines,
  grid,
  crosshatch,
  dots,
  crosshatch dots,
  fivepointed stars,
  sixpointed stars,
  bricks,
  checkerboard
}

\begin{document}

\getarraylength{Pattern}

\getarrayitem{Pattern}{1}

\getarrayitem{Pattern}{-2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Tarass It's a good occasion for learning a much better approach to arrays.